# Can I run the Grove image on BBB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, beagleboneblack, iot

I have a `BBB revision A5` and would like to fast track `AWS-iot` testing.

I am thinking of using the `BB Green` image as this might have some advantages.  Can I just download the `Grove image` and use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not be able to run the image on the 2 GB [Rev A or B eMMCs](http://elinux.org/Beagleboard:BeagleBoneBlack).  The [Rev C BBB eMMC](http://elinux.org/Beagleboard:BeagleBoneBlack) have been upgraded to 4 GB and will be able to run the image.

You will be able to run it on the SD card.  Most likely the I/O pins will correspond to the [Grove Cape for BeagleBone Series](http://www.seeedstudio.com/depot/Grove-Cape-for-BeagleBone-Series-p-1718.html) and only minor tweaks might be required.